# How can I copy a table with some cells that have an image inside from a doc to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I've copied Serge's script ([Serge insas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1368381/serge-insas))
But when there's an image inside a table cell, it isn't visible in the targetDoc.
Do you know what to do?

```
function copyDoc() {
  var sourceDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.create('CopyOf'+DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getName());
//  var targetDoc = DocumentApp.openById('another doc ID');
  var totalElements = sourceDoc.getNumChildren();
  
  for( var j = 0; j < totalElements; ++j ) {
    var body = targetDoc.getBody()
    var element = sourceDoc.getChild(j).copy();
    var type = element.getType();
    if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH ){
      body.appendParagraph(element);
    }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE){
      body.appendTable(element);
      }
    else if( type == DocumentApp.ElementType.LIST_ITEM){
      body.appendListItem(element);
      }
//    ...add other conditions (headers, footers...
    }
  targetDoc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [app-script google doc copy table with inline image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37206436/app-script-google-doc-copy-table-with-inline-image)

Comment: How was the image added? Can you provide a copy of the document, free of sensitive information?

Comment: Thank you, Diego! I tried that script also, but it erases all the cells and doesn´t copy the images.

Comment: Hi, Lamblichus! Thank  you  for asking. Here is an example of a simple document with a table and an image inside of it. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O220GsICkd7kjtZ5urm8VVCzh4MpOAIKFJlG3PaFxWM/edit?usp=sharing

And here is the screenacapture of what happens when I run the script to copy the document.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wEj7ifCsCOrF4knUGuW_fCwxh_V9C9T5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy image from one table cell to another within google documents using a google script (programmatically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53873919/how-to-copy-image-from-one-table-cell-to-another-within-google-documents-using-a)

Comment: Thanks, Lamblichus!
I´ve tried the last script proposed as an answer, but still it doesn´t copy the image.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NzRT4mQkNvFLTEhmxoaRAp3e9aJorc5R/view?usp=drivesdk

It amused me that it did copy the image when I set the source document as the target document.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k1GfZeaWj4vRvI8S3taDoM6LoZdy67Wj/view?usp=drivesdk